# System recommendation smart citizen measuring noise and air quality

Tags: noise, measurement

I really much like the idea of citizen science movement. After researching a couple of projects and tinkering around with Arduino (ESP8266) and Raspberry Pi I was not sure what to use. Especially the sensors seemed a really complex topic.

Then I came across the following projects and found them fascinating:

- [Smart Citizen](https://smartcitizen.me) - Barcelona based project measuring light, noise, temp., humidity, PM etc.
- [sensor.community](https://sensor.community) - Stuttgart based project focusing on PM and noise
- [safecast](https://safecast.org) - Tokyo based project focusing on radiation and PM

Considering the above platforms and the option to build something from scratch, what would you recommend? My focus so far is on noise and air quality, which I want to measure over time - more  may follow.

Any recommendations and hints into other directions would be really much appreciated!

Comment: Build something that matches your knowledge...

Comment: For noise, a microphone. For air quality, decide what aspects you want to measure and buy or develop sensors for that.

Answer (score 1):

One form of common wisdom in life is: only build it if you can't buy it.

> My focus so far is on noise and air quality, which I want to measure over time...

This seems that you're more interested in the environmental issues, rather than the electronic ones. So buy/borrow or purloin the requisite components. You needn't reinvent the sensors/controllers unless that's the bit of interest for you.

Note: Arduinos and Pis are relatively easy due to the massive global user base. Just ask, it's probably been done already :-)

And Hi.

Comment: Would you recommend another forum, as indeed my question is which platform is best for my purpose? My assumption was the community here know the platforms, do you know if there is a stackoverflow community better suited for my question?

Comment: @lony Oh God no. The Stackoverlow community is (nasty) if your question is not ultra-specific. Google "Stackoverflow complaints". It's a business thing beyond this scope. The people here are nicer.

Comment: @lony You want to monitor noise and air quality. So choose. Procrastination is so much worse than a command decision. Pick one, and we'll help you.